# MySQL Query order by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

I have a rows with (`firstname, lastname, phone, email`). What I want to make is a query which sort first by `concat(firstname, lastname) asc` and the rest rows, where the `firstname` and `lastname` are null have to come after the sorted by `concat(firstname, lastname) asc`and to be sorted depending on `phone/email` (if `phone` is null sort by `email`, if `email` is null sort by `phone`). Any suggestion can help me?

Comment: look for `case`, `coalesce`

Comment: Note that case/coalesce require compatible data types.

Answer (score 3):

You can put these rules into the `order by`.  I think these are:

```
order by (firstname is null and lastname is null) asc,
         concat(firstname, lastname),
         coalesce(phone, email)
```

I am not sure if the first condition should be `and` or `or`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table order by concat(firstname, lastname) asc,  (firstname is null and lastname is null) asc, coalesce(phone, email)
```